# React Router 6 in Electron - No routes matched location

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, electron

I am trying to use react-router v6 in an electron js application.

but it doesn't work for me.

This App works correctly without implementing the react-router!

When I use the react-router v6, I will get this message in the console, and doesn't show the content

> No routes matched location

**Project Structure**

[image]

In this Project, **index.html** file loads the **app.js** inside the **build** folder.

**index.js**

**App.jsx**

```
    import React from "react";
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import { Home, Blog } from "./pages";
    import "./App.scss";

    const Application = () => {
      return (
        <Router>
          <nav id="navigation">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <Link to="/">Home</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/blog">Blog</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <div id="content">
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
              <Route path="/blog" element={<Blog />} />
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </Router>
      );
    };

    export { Application };
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to use `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter`

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#hashrouter

Comment: This helped. I was using BrowserRouter earlier. Using HashRouter solved the problem

Comment: Any idea of why it works with HashRouter and not BrowserRouter ? What would it change using one or another ? It was mentioned not to use it unless required. Isn't there any "bypass" ? I think it had to be due to versions of some packages, I converted an old React project of mine with Electron and it worked fine after building.

Comment: seems promising but https://reactrouter.com/en/6.14.2/router-components/hash-router says "We strongly recommend you do not use HashRouter unless you absolutely have to." which makes me bit uneasy